# jetty web app multiple authentication options

Tags: java, web.xml, jetty-9

I have successfully set up jetty (Version: 9.4.32.v20200930) to serve my web application with FORM authentication. This is a deployed context XML setup with a web app folder, containing a WEB-INF folder, containing a web.xml file, etc.

I have also successfully set it up to use OpenID authentication by activating and configuring jetty's "openid" module.

Now I can switch authentication methods by simply changing the context XML and web.xml files and redeploying the web app.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to use both authentication methods at the same time, depending on user preference. Some users may have an OpenID account and log in this way; other users may only have "local" accounts so they should be able to use the FORM authentication method. Each type of user (OpenID/local) may have a different login URL; this is perfectly reasonable.

Obviously, changing context XML and web.xml files requires redeploying the app, so it is not a usable option.

Duplicating the app and deploying it twice would work but, concurrency considerations aside, this doesn't feel right at all.

Is there any way to have both authentication methods at the same time for a single web application?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to have more than one Jetty authentication mechanism enabled at the same time.

It would be useful if Jetty could support this use case, so I will investigate to see if this can be implemented. I have opened an [issue on the jetty project github](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/5442) to track the progress on this.